# what is this "cite" in the same line as edit and close

Tags: discussion

I must have missed something. What is this "cite"  in the same line as "edit" and "close" in a question, and "edit" and "flag" in an answer. Cite what and where?

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/189213/209806

Comment: I am no wiser for the link.  Where will the citation appear? The link also gives a process: click share???

Comment: @Qmechanic ok, I pressed share in one of my answers and out came facebook etc ( in which I am not registered) . If I were, would pressing share and then,, lets say facebook and then cite the link would appear on facebook? what are all those commands appearing when pressing "cite"?

Comment: Hi! Check my question: [What is the function of `cite` below each question & answer?](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/7056/); probably it is related (or dup?).

Comment: I personally *love* the bibtex.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what the confusion is. The `cite` button produces a [BibTeX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BibTeX) or [AMSRefs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMSRefs) bibliographic database entry that describes the question. The intended use case is for people who want to cite Stack Exchange posts in an academic paper, or similar document, written in LaTeX. You include the entry in your `.bib` file (or similar) and then compile the bibliography as usual. It also gives a suggested format for the citation's final look in the paper.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Thanks, it is also explained in the duplicate. (I searched for "cite" but did not see the duplicate question)

Comment: @dmckee Have you actually used it [in anger](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30939/is-used-in-anger-a-britishism-for-something)? I understand the use case in MO but I don't quite see the applicability here - I'd cite SE in, say, lecture notes or something, but not really in a journal publication.

Comment: @Emilo A couple times in documents prepared for class. I take care to do a thorough job of citing sources to set a good example.